# Python regex to replace everything between a string and a period followed by a parentheses

Tags: python, regex

`txt = **(Note:**  %Program Files%  is the default Program Files folder, usually C:\Program Files in Windows 2000, Server 2003, and XP (32-bit), Vista (32-bit), 7 (32-bit), and 8 (32-bit), or C:\Program Files (x86) in Windows XP (64-bit), Vista (64-bit), 7 (64-bit), and 8 (64-bit) **.)** ***IMPORTANT TEXT*** **(Note:**  %Application Data%   is the current user's Application Data folder, which is usually C:\Documents and Settings\{user name}\Application Data on Windows 2000, XP, and Server 2003, or C:\Users\{user name}\AppData\Roaming on Windows Vista, 7, and 8..  %Program Files%  is the default Program Files folder, usually C:\Program Files in Windows 2000, Server 2003, and XP (32-bit), Vista (32-bit), 7 (32-bit), and 8 (32-bit), or C:\Program Files (x86) in Windows XP (64-bit), Vista (64-bit), 7 (64-bit), and 8 (64-bit)**.)** ***IMPORTANT TEXT*** **(Note:**  %Application Data%   is the current user's Application Data folder, which is usually C:\Documents and Settings\{user name}\Application Data on Windows 2000, XP, and Server 2003, or C:\Users\{user name}\AppData\Roaming on Windows Vista, 7, and 8 **.)**`

I have a text like txt and I would like to remove everything that is between *(NOTE: * and *.)* , removing only the (**IMPORTANT TEXT**).  I have written this regex `\(Note:([^)]+\.\))` but it only finds the last Note. Also, I tried the `\(Note:([^)]+.\))` but that also consider the first closing parentheses. I am using `re.sub(\(Note:([^)]+.\)), '', txt)` Any idea?

Comment: Replace `[^)]` by `.` and set the multiline flag in `re.sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly this is really messy and you can probably optimize this but if the pattern is consistent this should work

<s>**(Note:**(.*?)**.)**</s>

Modifying yours just a tiny bit, this also works:

```
\(Note:(.+?\.\))
```

[image]